# How does Whatsapp know how to send notifications with a sender name by contacts

Tags: algorithm, mobile, architecture, chat, whatsapp

Imagine this:
You are in a Whatsapp Group. You name each of your friends differently (Obviously). And, each of your friends has a different contact name for you.

If someone sends a message in a group, Whatsapp sends a notification to all of the participants. How does Whatsapp know to send a Notification consisting of the contact name of each and every mobile phone?
Do they actually store the nicknames of all the contacts? It creates a hella amount of data.
It means if we are a group of 20 people, Whatsapp would store 20x20 = 400 rows indicating the relation between each participants and the other?

Hope I was able to walk you through the scenario,
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification will always contain a "id" of the contact(which will be the same for everyone). In the app, for each user, the application fetches the contact name that the user has saved for this "id" and uses that for displaying.

Comment: Correct. @Bar Goldinfeld -  what users see, and what system use, doesn't have to be the same thing.

Comment: So there's a technical mechanism that lets you change the Push Notification received from FCM??

Comment: For APNS, [yes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications). Not sure about FCM, but there must be something similar

Comment: does it answer your question @BarGoldinfeld. can you please accept the answer if yes, or add a comment if not